# How can I handle multiple parameters when I use combin function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I know that the combin function accepts the max 5 parameters, so I have to use .combine( ){ }.combine( ){ } in my Code A.

I think the Code A is not good way.

Code B is a optimized code.

1:  Code C is modified by me, is it correct?

2:  Is there the better way to handle to multiple  parameters for combine function?

**Code A**

```
data class HomeUIState(
    val loadingDataResult: EResult<List<MInfo>> = EResult.LOADING,
    val recordingState: ERecordState = ERecordState.STOPPED,
    val eSortBy: ESortBy = ESortBy.START_PRIORITY,

    val elapsedTime: String="00:00:00",

    val expandedListMInfoID: List<Int> = emptyList(),

    val playingMInfo: MInfo = MInfo(),
    val playState: EPlayState = EPlayState.STOPPED,

    val locateRecordID: Int = -1
)

private val _recordingState= MutableStateFlow(ERecordState.STOPPED)
    private val _eSortBy = MutableStateFlow(ESortBy.START_PRIORITY)
    private val _loadingDataResult = _eSortBy.flatMapLatest { handelMInfo.listAll(it)}
                                        .stateIn(
                                             viewModelScope,
                                             SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
                                             EResult.LOADING
                                          )
    private val _elapsedTime = MutableStateFlow("00:00:00")
    private val _expandedListMInfoID = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Int>())
    private val _playingMInfo = MutableStateFlow(MInfo())
    private val _playState = MutableStateFlow(EPlayState.STOPPED)
    private val _locateRecordID = MutableStateFlow(-1)
  
    val homeUIState: StateFlow<HomeUIState> =  combine(
        _loadingDataResult, _recordingState, _eSortBy, _elapsedTime, _expandedListMInfoID
    ) {
        loadingDataResult, recordingState, eSortBy, elapsedTime, expandedListMInfoID  ->

        val basedHomeUIState = HomeUIState(
            recordingState = recordingState,
            eSortBy = eSortBy,
            elapsedTime = elapsedTime,
            expandedListMInfoID = expandedListMInfoID
        )

        when (loadingDataResult) {
            is EResult.LOADING -> {
                basedHomeUIState.copy(loadingDataResult = EResult.LOADING)
            }

            is EResult.SUCCESS -> {
                basedHomeUIState.copy(
                    loadingDataResult = EResult.SUCCESS(loadingDataResult.data)
                )
            }

            is EResult.ERROR -> {
                basedHomeUIState.copy(loadingDataResult = EResult.ERROR(loadingDataResult.exception))
            }
        }
    }.combine(_playingMInfo) {
        homeUIState, playingMInfo -> homeUIState.copy(playingMInfo = playingMInfo)
    }.combine(_playState) {
        homeUIState, playState -> homeUIState.copy(playState = playState)
    }.combine(_locateRecordID) {
        homeUIState, locateRecordID -> homeUIState.copy(locateRecordID = locateRecordID)
    }
        . stateIn(
           viewModelScope,
           SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
           HomeUIState()
        )
```

**Code B**

```
private val _recordingState = MutableStateFlow(ERecordState.STOPPED)
...

private val baseHomeUIState: StateFlow<HomeUIState> = combine(
    _recordingState,
    _eSortBy,
    _elapsedTime,
    _expandedListMInfoID
) { recordingState, eSortBy, elapsedTime, expandedListMInfoID ->
    HomeUIState(
       ...
    )
}.stateIn(
    viewModelScope,
    SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    HomeUIState()
)

val homeUIState: StateFlow<HomeUIState> = combine(
    baseHomeUIState,
    _loadingDataResult,
    _playingMInfo,
    _playState,
    _locateRecordID
) { baseState, loadingDataResult, playingMInfo, playState, locateRecordID ->
    when (loadingDataResult) {
        is EResult.LOADING -> baseState.copy(loadingDataResult = EResult.LOADING)
        is EResult.SUCCESS -> baseState.copy(loadingDataResult = EResult.SUCCESS(loadingDataResult.data))
        is EResult.ERROR -> baseState.copy(loadingDataResult = EResult.ERROR(loadingDataResult.exception))
    }.copy(
        playingMInfo = playingMInfo,
        playState = playState,
        locateRecordID = locateRecordID
    )
}.stateIn(
    viewModelScope,
    SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    HomeUIState()
)
```

**Code C**

```
   private val _recordingState= MutableStateFlow(ERecordState.STOPPED)
   ...   

    private val baseHomeUIState = combine(
        _recordingState,
        _eSortBy,
        _elapsedTime,
        _expandedListMInfoID
    ) { recordingState, eSortBy, elapsedTime, expandedListMInfoID ->
        HomeUIState(
          ...
        )
    }

    val homeUIState: StateFlow<HomeUIState> = combine(
        baseHomeUIState,
        _loadingDataResult,
        _playingMInfo,
        _playState,
        _locateRecordID
    ) { baseState, loadingDataResult, playingMInfo, playState, locateRecordID ->
        when (loadingDataResult) {
            is EResult.LOADING -> baseState.copy(loadingDataResult = EResult.LOADING)
            is EResult.SUCCESS -> baseState.copy(loadingDataResult = EResult.SUCCESS(loadingDataResult.data))
            is EResult.ERROR -> baseState.copy(loadingDataResult = EResult.ERROR(loadingDataResult.exception))
        }.copy(
            playingMInfo = playingMInfo,
            playState = playState,
            locateRecordID = locateRecordID
        )
    }.stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
        HomeUIState()
    )
```

Comment: FYI, it's against the rules to post AI-generated content and it might get your question closed.

Comment: IMO, I would use a single Flow of some data class that has all the information to begin with so you don't have to combine them.

Comment: Thanks! How can I use  single Flow of some data  to do this? Could you give me some sample code ? You know there is a `data class HomeUIState(..)` in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution in my opinion is to split into smaller `Flow`s and keep in mind their update rate. Something like this:

```
private val screenState: StateFlow<ScreenState> = combine(
    _recordingState,
    _eSortBy,
    _expandedListMInfoID,
) { recordingState, eSortBy, expandedListMInfoID ->
    ScreenState(
        ...
    )
}.stateIn(
    viewModelScope,
    SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    ScreenState(),
)

private val gameState: StateFlow<GameState> = combine(
    _loadingDataResult,
    _playingMInfo,
    _playState,
    _locateRecordID,
) { loadingDataResult, playingMInfo, playState, locateRecordID ->
    GameState(
        ...
    )
}.stateIn(
    viewModelScope,
    SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    GameState(),
)

val homeUIState: StateFlow<HomeUIState> = combine(
    screenState,
    gameState,
    _elapsedTime,
) { screenState, gameState, elapsedTime ->
    HomeUiState(
        screenState,
        gameState,
        elapsedTime,
    )
}.stateIn(
    viewModelScope,
    SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    HomeUIState()
)
```

When you have a lot of content on the screen to update you should also consider the frequency of updates to improve performance. For example, you have a variable called `_elapsedTime`. If it updates every second maybe you would prefer to keep it on the root object and pass it directly to the composable that's displaying the time to avoid recomposition of any other component. Or, if you have a group of data that's often updated together you probably want them to be in the same object.

Comment: Thanks!   Do I need to append  `.stateIn(...) ` after both `private val screenState` and `private val gameState` ? 

I think  I need to append `.stateIn(...)`  only after `val homeUIState,` right?

Comment: You're right if you don't need to read them separately.

Answer (score 0):

> the combine function accepts the max 5 parameters

Seems it supports more than 5 parameters, see the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html). If you want to pass more than 5 parameter just wrap them into a collection of pass as varargs, and then the transform function gets an array:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! in your  code , f1, f2 .. f7 are the same Int types,  I use different types.

Comment: Right, you need to cast as 'it' is an array of objects